# $.mobile.changePage in jQuery Mobile - update visible URL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a changePage event in jQuery Mobile.

Basically I'd like to load a new page with a "pop" transition. Crucially I'd also like the displayed URL to update (so the user can link to the new page) and I'd like the page to appear in history.

Currently I'm trying:

```
 $('#mylink').click(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('/photo.html?p=14545', { transition: "pop"} );
 });     
 <a id="mylink">Click here</a>
```

However, this isn't updating the displayed URL, and the page also doesn't seem to load correctly.

Any advice on how to make sure the URL is correctly updated and displayed?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

note that this is an external URL, not a hash URL. I'm trying to find a way to go to the external page, and update the URL to that of the external page. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is now already working as you want it in JQM 1.0RC1.

Answer (score 4):

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r4DyU/1/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <p>This is Page 1</p>
        <button type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submit" value="submit-value" id="submit-button-1">Open Dialog</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <p>This is Page 2</p>
        <button type="submit" data-theme="e" name="submit" value="submit-value" id="submit-button-2">Close Dialog</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit-button-1').click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage($('#page2'), 'pop'); 
});

$('#submit-button-2').click(function() {
    alert('Going back to Page 1');
    $.mobile.changePage($('#page1'), 'pop'); 
});

// Or try this: Adding the URL
$('#submit-button-1').click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage('/photo.html?p=14545', 'pop'); 
});

$('#submit-button-2').click(function() {
    alert('Going back to Page 1');
    $.mobile.changePage('/photo.html?p=14545', 'pop'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I use `$.mobile.changePage('/photo.html?p=14545', 'pop');` then the URL switches to `test.html#/photo.html?p=14545`. For various reasons (bookmarking and avoiding calling unnecessary external libraries) I really need to load the external URL `photo.html?p=14545`. Is there a way to specify in changePage that this is a new URL, not a hash change, like using `external` on a link?

Comment: I think this is now already working as you want it in JQM 1.0RC1.

Answer (score 2):

$.mobile.changePage("#yourpage", { dataUrl: "#yourpage?x=1&y=2", transition: "fade" });

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the location hash you need to specify the new url in the changePage options paramter:

```
$.mobile.changePage('/photo.html?p=14545', {dataUrl: "/photo.html?p=14545", transition: "pop"});
```